# DebounceTime after first value in RxJS

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I need a specific behavior that I can't get with the RxJS operators. The closest would be to use DebounceTime only for values entered after the first one, but I can't find a way to do it. I have also tried with ThrottleTime but it is not exactly what I am looking for, since it launches intermediate calls, and I only want one at the beginning that is instantaneous, and another at the end, nothing else.

**ThrottleTime**

```
throttleTime(12 ticks, { leading: true, trailing: true })

source:             --0--1-----2--3----4--5-6---7------------8-------9---------
throttle interval:  --[~~~~~~~~~~~I~~~~~~~~~~~I~~~~~~~~~~~I~~~~~~~~~~~]--------
output:             --0-----------3-----------6-----------7-----------9--------


source_2:           --0--------1------------------2--------------3---4---------
throttle interval:  --[~~~~~~~~~~~I~~~~~~~~~~~]---[~~~~~~~~~~~]--[~~~~~~~~~~~I~
output_2:           --0-----------1---------------2--------------3-----------4-
```

**DebounceTime**

```
debounceTime(500)

source:             --0--1--------3------------4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11--13----------------
debounce_interval:  -----[~~~~~]--[~~~~~]--------------------------[~~~~~]----------
output:             -----------1--------3--------------------------------13---------
```

**What I want**

```
debounceTimeAfterFirst(500) (?)

source:             --0--1--------3------------4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11--13----------------
debounce_interval:  -----[~~~~~]--[~~~~~]--------------------------[~~~~~]----------
output:             --0--------1--3------------4-------------------------13---------
```

As you see, the debounce time is activated when a new value is entered. If the debounce time passes and any new value has been entered, it stops the listening the debounceTime action and waits to start a new one.

**Edit**: I forgot to comment that this must be integrated with **NgRx’s Effects**, so it must be a continuous stream that mustn't be completed. Terminating it would probably cause it to stop listening for dispatched actions.

Comment: So, in your example, why do 0 and 4 not start debounce_interval, but 1, 3, an 13 do? What's happening with 5-11?

Comment: It's the normal behaviour for DebounceTime https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounceTime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use a `throttle` combined with a `debounceTime`:

- **throttle**: *from [Documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/throttle)* Emit value on the leading edge of an interval, but suppress new values until durationSelector has completed.
- **debounceTime**: *from [Documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/debouncetime)* Discard emitted values that take less than the specified time between output.

I would use a throttle stream to get the raising edge (the first emission) and then the debounce stream would give us the falling edge.

```js
const source = fromEvent(document.getElementsByTagName('input'), 'keyup').pipe(
  pluck('target', 'value')
);

const debounced = source.pipe(
  debounceTime(4000),
  map((v) => `[d] ${v}`)
);

const effect = merge(
  source.pipe(
    throttle((val) => debounced),
    map((v) => `[t] ${v}`)
  ),
  debounced
);

effect.subscribe(console.log);
```

See [RxJS StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/use-first-and-debounce?devtoolsheight=33&file=index.ts) with the console open to see the values changing.

I prepared the setup to adapt it to **NgRx** which you mention. The effect I got working is:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class FooEffects {
  switchLight$ = createEffect(() => {
    const source = this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType('[App] Switch Light'),
      pluck('onOrOff'),
      share()
    );
    const debounced = source.pipe(debounceTime(1000), share());
    return merge(source.pipe(throttle((val) => debounced)), debounced).pipe(
      map((onOrOff) => SetLightStatus({ onOrOff }))
    );
  });

  constructor(private actions$: Actions) {}
}
```

See [NgRx StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngrx-first-and-debounce-rest?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/foo.effects.ts) with the proposed solution working in the context of an Angular NgRx application.

- **share**: This operator prevents the downstream paths to simultaneously fetch the data from all the way up the chain, instead they grab it from the point where you place share.

I also tried to adapt @martin's `connect()` approach. But I don't know how @martin would "reset" the system so that after a long time if a new source value is emitted would not debounce it just in the same manner as you first run it, @martin, feel free to fork it and tweak it to make it work, I'm curious about your approach, which is very smart. I didn't know about `connect()`.

@avicarpio give it a go on your application and let us know how it goes :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it like the following, even though I can't think of any easier solution right now (I'm assuming you're using RxJS 7+ with `connect()` operator):

```
connect(shared$ => shared$.pipe(
  exhaustMap(value => merge(
    of(value),
    shared$.pipe(debounceTime(1000)),
  ).pipe(
    take(2),
  )),
)),
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-qwoesj?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

`connect()` will share the source Observable and lets you reuse it in its project function multiple times. I'm using it only to use the source Observable inside another chain.

`exhaustMap()` will ignore all `next` notifications until its inner Observable completes. In this case the inner Observable will immediately reemit the current value (`of(value)`) and then use `debounceTime()`. Any subsequent emission from source is ignored by `exhaustMap()` because the inner Observable hasn't completed yet but is also passed to `debounceTime()`. Then `take(2)` is used to complete the chain after `debounceTime()` emits and the whole process can repeat when source emits because `exhaustMap()` won't ignore the `next` notification (its inner Observable has completed).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that this needs to be inside an effect, so I can't make this works in my code. I edited the main thread with that info. Thanks for the reply anyway, and if you come up with anything I'll be glad to read it :)

Comment: Why you can't use it in an effect? The outer chain doesn't get completed. You can see that in the demo link. If it did complete then it wouldn't work repeatedly but you can see it does.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a custom operator that (as far s I can tell) does what you're after.

The two key insights here are:

1. Use connect so that you can subscribe to the source twice, once to ignore emissions with `exhaustMap` and another to inspect and debounce emissions with `switchMap`
2. Create an internal token so that you know when to exit without a debounced emission. (Insures that from your example above, the 4 is still emitted).

```ts
function throttleDebounceTime<T>(interval: number): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  // Use this token's memory address as a nominal token
  const resetToken = {};

  return connect(s$ => s$.pipe(
    exhaustMap(a => s$.pipe(
      startWith(resetToken),
      switchMap(b => timer(interval).pipe(mapTo(b))),
      take(1),
      filter<T>(c => c !== resetToken),
      startWith(a)
    ))
  ));
}
```

example:

```
of(1,2,3,4).pipe(
  throttleDebounceTime(500)
).subscribe(console.log);

// 1 [...0.5s wait] 4
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the operator i wrote:

```
export function throttleDebounce<T>(time: number): OperatorFunction<T, T> {
  return (source: Observable<T>): Observable<T> => {
    const debounced = source.pipe(debounceTime(time), share());

    return merge(source.pipe(throttle(() => debounced)), debounced).pipe(map((value) => value));
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**